# Long running operation did not complete, continuing in background when I use Database.convertLead

Tags: apex, lead-conversion

For some reason when I use Database.convertLead in the code I receive the following Statement from the developer console:

Long running operation did not complete, continuing in background

I know that there is probably something wrong with my code - I just really cannot understand. I have all my required fields in place.

```
public void convertOne(Sobject masterRecord, Sobject mergedRecord)
    {
        Database.LeadConvert lc = new Database.LeadConvert();

        lc.setLeadId(mergedRecord.Id);
        lc.setConvertedStatus('Qualified');
        lc.setAccountId( ((Id)masterRecord.get('AccountId')));
        lc.setContactId(masterRecord.Id);
        lc.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(true);


        Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code, exactly; it's simply taking longer than the 
Developer Console is waiting to wait. You will need to check your console logs to see where the extra time is going off to. It might be a problem with a Process or Flow that is taking too long to complete, database contention, or something else. Without seeing your logs, there's really no way to tell immediately why this is happening. You may also want to write a unit test for this method and see if you can an abnormally long CPU time or an error.

Comment: What are the leading indicators in the logs that a PB or Flow is eating extra time?

Comment: @MatthewMetros There'll be lines like FLOW_START and FLOW_STOP. The timestamps on the left indicate the time a particular action was logged. You can use these to tell how long something is taking.